# How to automatically create Makefile dependency files in a hidden folder?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make, prerequisites

I want to automatically create Makefile dependency files in a hidden folder but I can't find an example of how to create dependency files automatically. Everything concerning makefile is gcc, but I am using not for gcc and I am not too familiar with gcc.

I have a makefile like this.

importf = .mkfiles/import
import: $(importf)
$(importf):
        @$(call make_function,0,import)

Could you please help me what I am missing in the makefile.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Makefiles that build dependency files using gcc rely on gcc to do the actual building (and tell gcc which files to build, and where, and when). How will you build the files? (As a rule, you can't do something with Make until you know how to do it *without* Make.

Comment: With regard to makefiles and dependencies you might want to [read this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).